# Слушатель в Android приложении

Tags: java, android

Разрабатываю приложение, где есть кабинет пользователей со своими паролями, именами и временем открытия смены. Необходимо по прохождению 24 часов-любой из открытой смены-оповещать `Toast` или др.средствами "Смена открыта 24 часа".

Все это реализовал, но могу использовать только в `onCreate()`, а как сделать в `onResume()`, чтобы был некий слушатель? Т.е. во время работы приложения, чтобы выводился `Toast` а не при запуске как у меня сейчас? Подумываю о `while(true)` но боюсь нагрузить приложение, пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: `onResume()` не "во время работы приложения", этот колбэк срабатывает так же, как и `onCreate()` при старте активити. Чтобы получить событие через определенное время работы приложения вам нужно устанавливать таймер на нужное время при открытии вашей смены и по событию завершения таймера производить свои действия.

Comment: Вам будет полезно почитать это: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, это то что вам нужно: создаём новый поток, например, в `onCreate`, ждём в нём 24 часа и после этого выводим тост.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(24*3600*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
}).start();
```

Comment: который утечет, когда активити прибьется системой

Comment: О ужас. Не делайте так никогда.